# What devices can I ask questions about on superuser?

Tags: support

The [superuser site topic definition](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) says we can ask about computer software, so long as it doesn't run on electronic devices. Can anyone provide an example of a non-electronic device that runs "computer software"? If not, then the rules would seem to say that we can't ask about computer software that actually runs...

Or maybe, if we read between the lines, there are specific OSes that are banned? But if that were the case, then why not just list said OSes?

Comment: I think the context and the remainder of that sentence defines the term decently well makes it pretty clear what is and is not on topic.

Answer (score 5):

"electronic devices" in the help centre refers to things like Smart TVs, fridges, toasters, IoT devices all of which (may) contain computer chips and software.

These are all excluded from SuperUser.